# Why aren't these constraints working?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, constraints, autolayout

I am programatically setting the following constraints on three views inside a UIView:

```
UIView *view1 = ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view;
UIView *view2 = ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).view;
UIView *view3 = ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]).view;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2, view3);
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[view1(==320)]-0-[view2(==320)]-0-[view3(==320)]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

My intention is that each view is 320px wide, sitting flush against one-another with no gap, and view one up against the left edge of the containing UIView.

However, when compiled, the views are laid out on-top of one-another and I get the following in the console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x211811c0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0xc683790]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xc683320 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x21179820 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0xc683790.midX == UIView:0xc683320.midX - 340>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x211793d0 H:[UIView:0xc6a50c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xc683320 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x21179390 H:[UIView:0xc6a50c0(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x21179350 H:[UIView:0xc6a05f0]-(0)-[UIView:0xc6a50c0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x211563d0 H:[UIView:0xc6a05f0(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x21156390 H:[UIView:0xc683790]-(0)-[UIView:0xc6a05f0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x21179350 H:[UIView:0xc6a05f0]-(0)-[UIView:0xc6a50c0]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

for all of your views, it usually is enough to solve this kind of problem.